# write a Pandas dataframe to a .txt file

Tags: python, pandas

My code writes a txt file with lots of data. I'm trying to print a pandas dataframe into that txt file as part of my code but can't use .write() as that only accepts strings.

How do I take a pandas dataframe, stored as DF1 for example, and print it in the file?

I've seen similar questions but those are aimed at creating a txt file solely for the dataframe, I would just like my dataframe to appear in a txt file

Comment: I don't understand the distinction between what you found in your research and what you want to achieve. Please illustrate what you're looking for.

Comment: I've currently written lots to the existing txt file by using .write() and would like to print the dataframe to the file and then continue adding more afterwards. Other methods write a separate txt file solely for the dataframe

Comment: This might be a noobie reply, but have you tried simply converting the entire df to str?

Answer (score 10):

use the `to_string` method, and then you can use `write` with the mode set to `append` (`'a'`)

```
tfile = open('test.txt', 'a')
tfile.write(df.to_string())
tfile.close()
```

---

Sample Data

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'id': np.arange(1,6,1),
                   'val': list('ABCDE')})
```

test.txt

```
This line of text was here before.
```

Code

```
tfile = open('test.txt', 'a')
tfile.write(df.to_string())
tfile.close()
```

Output: test.txt

```
This line of text was here before.
   id val
0   1   A
1   2   B
2   3   C
3   4   D
4   5   E
```

Comment: how about if i don't want to index column?

Comment: df.to_string(index=False)

Answer (score 4):

Pandas DataFrames have `to_string()`, `to_json()` and `to_csv()` methods that may be helpful to you, see:

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_string.html

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html

Example of writing a text file to a string. Use 'w' flag to write and 'a' to append to a file.

```
example_string = df1.to_string()
output_file = open('file.txt','a')
output_file.write(example_string)
output_file.close()
```

If you are only looking to put certain information in the text file, you can do that using either pandas or json methods to select it, etc. and see the docs links above as well.

Before OP commented about appending I originally wrote an example about json. `json` supports a `dump()` method to help write to a file. However, in most cases, its not the most ideal format to keep appending output to vs. csv or txt. In case its useful to anyone:

```
import json 

filename = 'file.json'

with open(filename, 'w') as file:
    json.dump(df1.to_json(), file)
```

Comment: Sorry edited it, I started an answer and hit submit when a call came in, came back and finished it with to_json, to_csv, to_string: all are string formats. The OP's stated difficulty was getting a string representation of the dataframe for .write()

Comment: The original question didn't have anything about appending, it was a later comment. I revised to put 'a' and describe the difference between 'w' and 'a' flag. I can go back again and re-order it so the txt is described first LOL

Comment: how about if i don't want to index column?

Comment: try:
df.to_string(index=False)