# How to make my data frame exactly the same after converting it to .txt file

Tags: python, dataframe, web-scraping

After extracting some text, i saved them as a dataframe and saved it as a .txt file, but the format are not the same how can i make them the same and get rid of the quote.

```
    Yoruba                                   Meaning
1   Adìẹ funfun kò mọ ara rẹ̀lágbà           Respect yourself
2   Ọbẹ̀ kìí gbé inú àgbà mì                 You should be able to keep secrets
3   À ń pe gbẹ́nàgbẹ́nà ẹyẹ àkókó ń yọjú      Never think too highly of yourself
4   Díẹ̀ díẹ̀ nimú ẹlẹ́dẹ̀ẹ́ fi ń wọgbà          Attend to a small problem before it becomes un...
5   Ilé ọba tójó ẹwà ló bùsi                Every cloud has a silver lining
6   Ile oba t'o jo, ewa lo busi             Necessity is mother of invention, creativity i...
```

after converting to .txt file this is what i got

```
concat.to_csv('yoruba_V1.txt', index = None, sep=' ')


Yoruba Meaning
"Adìẹ funfun kò mọ ara rẹ̀lágbà" "Respect yourself"
"Ọbẹ̀ kìí gbé inú àgbà mì" "You should be able to keep secrets"
"À ń pe gbẹ́nàgbẹ́nà ẹyẹ àkókó ń yọjú" "Never think too highly of yourself"
"Díẹ̀ díẹ̀ nimú ẹlẹ́dẹ̀ẹ́ fi ń wọgbà" "Attend to a small problem before it becomes uncontrollable"
"Ilé ọba tójó ẹwà ló bùsi" "Every cloud has a silver lining"
"Ile oba t'o jo, ewa lo busi" "Necessity is mother of invention, creativity is often achieved after overcoming many
```

Comment: The top answer to this thread may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51829923/write-a-pandas-dataframe-to-a-txt-file

Comment: What do you need this for?

Comment: This link above doesn't correspond with question

Comment: @AMC I'm trying to create a dataset and save as .txt