# How to write specific values from a Pandas (Python) dataframe to a specific place in a file (i.e., after an identifier)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, file-io

I have a file that's made up of entries like:

```
A       first = 4 | 1_3_5_4        Name1                                  
labelToSkip
i = 1000000 j = -3 k = -15
end

B       first = 4 | 9_2_2_4        Name2                                  
labelToSkip
i = 150000 j = -3 k = -20
end
...
```

I have managed to construct a Pandas dataframe (df) that contains data I have read in and modified from another file.  The dataframe looks like this:

```
    i      j      k     
0   unit1  unit2  unit3
1   1000   100    84      
2  -3000   200    60       
3  -2000   90     195      
4   900    40     209
```

Now I want to choose a row from the dataframe (like row 3) and put the i, j, k values in the first file.

For example, I would want to put the i, j, k values from row 3 of the dataframe:

```
3  -2000   90     195
```

in place of the i, j, k values in an entry of my choosing (like "B") to get:

```
B       first = 4 | 9_2_2_4        Name2                                  
labelToSkip
i = -2000 j = 90 k = 195
end
```

In reality, the entries are quite complicated and the values I need to replace are not always on the third line of the entry.  The main thing I need help with is how to find (1) "B" or "Name2" in the file and then replace the value after a specific identifier under "B" or "Name2."

I apologize for not providing an attempt.  I know how to write a dataframe to a .txt file (for example, from this post: [write a Pandas dataframe to a .txt file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51829923/write-a-pandas-dataframe-to-a-txt-file)).  I have also found out how to replace specific values within a dataframe.  However, I can't find any information on how to put specific values from a dataframe after an identifier in an external file.  If anyone could please provide a hint, I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of possible solutions is to use `re` module:

```py
import re

idx = 3
to_replace = "B"

with open("input_file.txt", "r") as f_in:
    file_string = f_in.read()

    i, j, k = df.loc[idx, ["i", "j", "k"]]

    file_string = re.sub(
        rf"^({to_replace}\s.*?)i = \S+ j = \S+ k = \S+",
        f"\g<1>i = {i} j = {j} k = {k}",
        file_string,
        flags=re.M | re.S,
    )

with open("output_file.txt", "w") as f_out:
    f_out.write(file_string)
```

---

`output_file.txt` will contain:

```
A       first = 4 | 1_3_5_4        Name1
labelToSkip
i = 1000000 j = -3 k = -15
end

B       first = 4 | 9_2_2_4        Name2
labelToSkip
i = -2000 j = 90 k = 195
end
```

---

`input_file.txt` contains:

```
A       first = 4 | 1_3_5_4        Name1
labelToSkip
i = 1000000 j = -3 k = -15
end

B       first = 4 | 9_2_2_4        Name2
labelToSkip
i = 150000 j = -3 k = -20
end
```

Comment: thank you so much.  My output file doesn't show any change compared to my input file.  This will be my fault!  There's clearly something I don't understand.  One thing is "idx."  May I please confirm that it is the row of the dataframe, df?

Comment: @Ant Yes, `idx` should be  valid index into your  dataframe. You can debug pring `i, j, k` to see if they hold right values.

Comment: @Andrey Kesely, thank you. They do, so the problem must be with writing the values to the file.  I will look into it!

Comment: @Andrey Kesely, thank you so much!  I got it to work with my input.  Really appreciate your trouble.