# How to skip a value when replacing values in an external file with values from a dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, file-io

I have a file that's made up of entries like:

```
A       first = 4 | 1_3_5_4        Name1                                  
labelToSkip
i = 1000000 j = -3 k = -15
end

B       first = 4 | 9_2_2_4        Name2                                  
labelToSkip
i = 150000 j = -3 k = -20
end
...
```

I asked this question about how to replace certain values in the file with corresponding values from a Pandas dataframe like:

```
    i      j      k     
0   unit1  unit2  unit3
1   1000   100    84      
2  -3000   200    60       
3  -2000   90     195      
4   900    40     209
```

[How to write specific values from a Pandas (Python) dataframe to a specific place in a file (i.e., after an identifier)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77566914/how-to-write-specific-values-from-a-pandas-python-dataframe-to-a-specific-plac/77567039)

I got a great solution.  However, I have some lines in my file where only the i and k values need to be replaced.  I.e., the dataframe looks like:

```
    i      k     
0   unit1  unit3
1   1000   84      
2  -3000   60       
3  -2000   195      
4   900    209
```

So I would want this result (for example). Here, I use the third row of values from the dataframe to replace only the values in the "i" and "k" fields of "B" in the file:

```
A       first = 4 | 1_3_5_4        Name1                                  
labelToSkip
i = 1000000 j = -3 k = -15
end

B       first = 4 | 9_2_2_4        Name2                                  
labelToSkip
i = -2000 j = -3 k = 195
end
...
```

However, in this situation, nothing happens when I run the solution.  I have tried changing "idx" to 2.  I even tried changing idx to "1" and running it for only i (having removed anything related to j and k) and then k.  That doesn't work either.  I haven't been able to find anything online about how to ignore/skip a field.  If anyone has a hint, I would be grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adapt the solution to not consider a fixed line with multiple fields, but rather the fields individually. Here we split on `\n\n` to handle the individual blocks separately.

```
import re

idx = 3
to_replace = 'B'

with (open('input_file.txt', 'r') as f_in,
      open('output_file.txt', 'w') as f_out):
    s = df.loc[idx]
    pat = r'\b(%s)\b(\s*=\s*)(\d+)' % '|'.join(s.index)
    
    f_out.write('\n\n'.join(
         re.sub(pat, lambda m: fr'{m.group(1)}{m.group(2)}{s.loc[m.group(1)]}',
                 block, flags=re.M | re.S)
         if block.startswith(to_replace) else block
         for block in re.split('\n\n', f_in.read())
         )  
               )
```

Output:

```
A       first = 4 | 1_3_5_4        Name1                                  
labelToSkip
i = 1000000 j = -3 k = -15
end

B       first = 4 | 9_2_2_4        Name2                                  
labelToSkip
i = 150000 j = -3 k = -20
end
```

Comment: thank you very much.  Apologies--there's something simple I don't understand.  I don't see where the replacement values are specified in your example.  For example, where is the "-2000" coming from?

Comment: @Ant that's a copy-paste mistake, I think I had first used the original code and copied that as input. It's working as expected ;)

Comment: I think the mistake is mine.  I wasn't clear in my question.  I will edit it!

Comment: I modified my question.  If you have time, I would be grateful to find out what values your code replaces.  I am probably being very silly but can't identify where in your code the replacement values are specified.

Comment: It's replaced in `s.loc[m.group(1)]`. `m` references the regex match and group 1/2/3 reference the `xxx` / `=` / `123`, using the captured value `xxx` to get the matching value in the series `s`